# Max number of index requests in a elasticsearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, lucene, threadpool, amazon-opensearch

My objective is to calculate how many index requests can a elasticsearch cluster hold in it's queue before starting rejecting it.

My elasticsearch cluster(v6.8) has 8 data nodes of r5.xlarge instance i.e. 4 vCPU's.
In the Elasticsearch documentation it is mentioned:

> For index/delete operations. Thread pool type is fixed with a size of
> number of available processors, queue_size of 200. The maximum size
> for this pool is 1 + # of available processors.

So, according to me each node has a thread pool of 4 as number of processors is 4. The queue size for the same is 200.

So for 8 nodes -> assuming all threads are busy servicing an index request -> My cluster can hold no. of nodes * queue size number of index requests in queue before it starts rejecting i.e. 8*200 = 1600.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

Nearly correct.

Each node has a thread pool of 5 (1 + 4 as number of processors is 4).

And index/delete operation are treated as a whole. Your cluster can hold no. of nodes * queue size number of index/delete requests in queue before it starts rejecting i.e. 8*200 = 1600.

Comment: Worth noting that from [7.9 onwards](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/modules-threadpool.html), the `write` queue size went form 200 to 10000. It might be worth considering an upgrade, as 6.8 is EOL and [not maintained anymore](https://www.elastic.co/support/eol)